# Is a definite article needed before "sleep"?

Tags: definite-articles

Do I need a definite article before "sleep" in the following sentence?

> How do they call in English that yellowish substance that is gathered
>   in the corner of a human eye during **the** sleep?

Comment: I wouldn't use it. You are not referring to a *specific* kind of sleep, but *sleep* in general.

Comment: Definitely not.  It reads much more natural without the _the_.

Comment: In your example sleep is an abstract noun, so you shouldn't use the before it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I actually can't think of any example where you'd use the definite article for the meaning of *sleep* in your sample sentence.

However, it's interesting to note that the word used for said yellowish substance is also *sleep*. And for this meaning of *sleep*, the definite article is appropriate. E.g. I wiped **the sleep** from my eyes.

Comment: Very interesting point. I had always taken that as a metaphor, rather than a description of rheum.  And *wiping the sleep* implies getting rid of all of it, whereas *wiping sleep* is just the gesture.

Comment: "The sleep of a laborer is sweet, whether he eats little or much, but the abundance of a rich man permits him no sleep."—Ecclesiastes 5:12. "Well, if you must you must. I suppose that you need the sleep of the just."—Elvis Costello.

Comment: @PeterShor thanks for the examples. It was inevitable that someone would take up the challenge. :)

Comment: As stuff in the eye, 'sleep' is an uncountable noun: 'You've got sleep in your eye, wipe it off'. 'Wiping the sleep.. ' suggests to me waking up properly after waking.

Answer (score 3):

As per the other answers, the article is obligatory absent here.  But you could avoid the issue by saying, instead, *when you sleep*.  An idiomatic version of the question would be:

*What's the English for that yellowish stuff that gathers in the corner of your eye when you sleep?*

(*How do they call* sounds foreign, and the passive *is gathered* wrongly implies an agent who gathers, which the middle *gathers* avoids.  *Human eye* and *substance* are both fine, but rather formal sounding.)

(BTW: the answer in my dialect of English is *sleepy dust*, but I know that other dialects have different names for it.)

Comment: What dialect is this?

Comment: Australian.  (I live, work, and write in Britain / British English, but all my "childish" words are Australian.)

Comment: I don't see that 'the stuff that gathers' implies an agent - it gathers of its own accord. It would suggest an agent if it were 'the stuff that is gathered' - passive construction without an agent stated.

Comment: That's exactly what I said.